# Evolution of reduced density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

Suppose we have two density matrices of an n-partite system, $\rho$, $\rho'$, with $\rho$ $\neq$ $\rho'$, but $\rho_A$ = $\rho_A'$, where A is a certain subset of the n parties. Is it true that $(U$$\rho$$ $$U^{-1}$$)_A$ = $(U$$\rho'$$ $$U^{-1}$$)_A$, where U is a unitary operator acting on the whole system of n parties?

Comment: I'm not sure. But maybe you could do the 2N case by trying out a general unitary operator like an euler angle and seeing if it holds true. Then you could try the 3N case and see if the same thing applies..

Comment: How many examples did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $\rho_1 = \frac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\rho_2 = \frac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. From those, construct two density matrices
$$ \rho = \rho_1 \otimes \rho_1 , \quad \rho' = \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2 $$
on the full Hilbert space $\mathbb C^2 \otimes \mathbb C^2$. Note that $\operatorname{tr}_B \rho = \operatorname{tr}_B \rho' = \rho_1$.

Now we define the unitary $U$ that swaps the two subspaces:
$$ U|1,1\rangle = |1,1\rangle, \quad U|1,2\rangle = |2,1\rangle, \quad U|2,1\rangle = |1,2\rangle, \quad U|2,2\rangle = |2,2\rangle. $$
It's easy to see that
$$ \operatorname{tr}_B U \rho U^\dagger = \rho_1 , \quad \text{but} \quad \operatorname{tr}_B U\rho'U^\dagger = \rho_2 .$$